# Laravel need data from two different collections in for each

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a for each loop to iterate over the collection of records. It has the user_id, but not the other user credentials. I created another collection of user. How do I include this in my iteration?

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request, $id)
{

 $thoughts = Thought::where('id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100)->get();
 $user = User::where('id', $thoughts->user_id);


return view('backend.pages.thought_list', compact('thoughts, user'));
}
```

View

```
    @foreach ($thoughts as $thought)
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">{{ $user->username}} <span class="user_id_thought">ID - {{ $user->user_id}}</span></td>
      <td class="col-md-1">{{ $thought->response }}</td>
      <td>{{ $thought->thought_type }}</td>
      <td>{{ $thought->id }}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

How do I display my users variable in the loop. Or is there a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eager Loading is the perfect use case for your requirement in my opinion.

e.g.

```
 $thoughts = Thought::with('user')->get();

    foreach ($thoughts as $thought) {
        echo $thought->user->name;
    }
```

For more details see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading